# Duda con modelo relacional base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Intento "dibujar" un modelo de base de datos en el que habrá una tabla de entrenamientos y su correspondiente detalle con varios registros según ejercicios asignados a un entrenamiento.

Esta primera parte, en la que se crea un entrenamiento y sus lineas de detalle, es creada por un usuario con  un rol 'X'.

Mi duda viene cuando los usuarios 'Y' a los que se les asigna este entrenamiento tienen que editar el entrenamiento propuesto para indicar los resultados del mismo.

En la práctica tengo:

- Tabla entrenamiento
- Tabla detalle entrenamiento (N lineas de entrenamiento)
- Tabla resultado entrenamiento

La última tabla es la que no se con cual de las dos inmediatamente anteriores relacionarla, si con la general o con la de detalle.

Comment: ¿El resultado es el del entrenamiento o de los ejercicios? Por otro lado te sugiero usar nombres más acordes con las entidades reales, en vez de detalle_entrenamiento, directamente ejercicios.

Answer (score 1):

Si el resultado es algo total, por ejemplo un digito que indique como fue el entrenamiento en conjunto, la tabla resultado entrenamiento debe relacionarse con entrenamiento.

Si el resultado es algo detallado, por ejemplo, un total por cada detalle de entrenamiento (algo mucho mas detallado), deberias relacionarlo con la tabla detalle de entrenamiento.

Answer (score 1):

pues dependera de que resultados cargaran los usuarios "Y", si cargaran un solo resultado para todo el entrenamiento entonces relacionala con entrenamientos.. si cargaran un resultado por cada linea de entrenamiento entonces relacionala con detalles